# Error Message: Can't call method "do" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, sqlite, xml-parsing, perl-module

```
# #################################################
#       Subroutine to add data to the table BlastSearch
#       Could be redone to be more general, but it seems more 
#       efficient to add data as it is pulled from the xml.
# ################################################# 
sub addData {
    my (@data, $dbhandle) = @_;
    print join(", ", @data) . "\n";
    my $sqlcmd = "insert into BlastSearch values('" . join("','",@data) . "')";
    $dbhandle->do($sqlcmd) or die $DBI::errstr;
}
```

This give the error message "Can't call method "do" on an undefined value." Is there anything in this particular method that is causing the problem? I can add more of the script if needed. My only guess is that it has to do with '@data,' which is filled in the code below:

```
# #################################################
#       Subroutine to find the:
#           Accession id
#           e-value (Hsp_evalue)
#           number of identites (Hsp_identity)
#       of the top five matches.
# #################################################
sub parseBlastXML {
    my ($file, $dbhandle) = @_;
    my $xml = new XML::Simple();
    my $data = $xml->XMLin($file, forcearray=>[qw(Hit)], keyattr=>[]);
    my $entry_node = $data->{BlastOutput_iterations};
    my $iterhit = $entry_node->{Iteration}->{Iteration_hits}->{Hit};

    #quick find of uniprotID
    my $uniProtID = substr($file, 0, 6);

    my $count = 0;
    foreach my $val (@$iterhit) {
        my @dataarray;
        if ($val->{Hit_hsps} && $count < 5) {
            print "\n";
            print "Hit accession: " . $val->{Hit_accession} . "\n"; 
            print "e-value: " . $val->{Hit_hsps}->{Hsp}->{Hsp_evalue} . "\n"; 
            print "number of ID's: " . $val->{Hit_hsps}->{Hsp}->{Hsp_identity} . "\n";
            push(@dataarray, $val->{Hit_accession}); 
            push(@dataarray, $val->{Hit_hsps}->{Hsp}->{Hsp_evalue}); 
            push(@dataarray, $val->{Hit_hsps}->{Hsp}->{Hsp_identity});
            push(@dataarray, $uniProtID);

            addData(@dataarray, $dbhandle);

            $count ++;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if anyone has any better way to add values to a row of an sqlite table than array and join, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a bug as `@data` will always slurp all the values in `@_`, leaving `$dbhandle` undefined.

```
sub addData {
    my (@data, $dbhandle) = @_;    # $dbhandle will always be undefined
```

To fix, you need to reorder your arguments, and always have the array last in the assignment.

```
sub addData {
    my ( $dbhandle, @data ) = @_;

    ...;
}

sub parseBlastXML {
    ...;
    addData( $dbhandle, @dataarray );
```

Note: it would also be possible to [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) the dbh off the end of the parameter list.  However, such a coding style is not a good idea.

Comment: Or `my $dbhandle = pop; my @data = @_;` if you want to keep the arguments in the current order.

Comment: Added note about pulling off from the end of the list.  Not recommended though.

Comment: I just flipped it in both places. Awesome answer, I would not have gotten that on my own. Still too new to Perl. Thanks!

Comment: @Stats4224: It's also bad form to `do` an SQL string with embedded values. You should `prepare` a string with placeholders and pass the actual values in a call to `execute`.

Answer (score 1):

*"Additionally, if anyone has any better way to add values to a row of an sqlite table than array and join, it'd be much appreciated."*

Is your `@data` array always the same size? I presume so, as you've specified no column list in your `INSERT` statement, so the best way is to write

```
sub add_data {
    my ($dbhandle, @data) = @_;
    my $insert = $dbhandle->prepare('INSERT INTO BlastSearch VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $insert->execute(@data) or die $DBI::errstr;
}
```

with the correct number of `?` placeholders, obviously. The `prepare` call is like compiling the statement, and ideally you should do it just once when your program first starts, after which you can call `execute` as many times as you like with different parameters.

If `@data` *does* vary in size, then all isn't lost. You can just do something like this

```
    my $insert = sprintf 'INSERT INTO BlastSearch VALUES (%)',
        join ', ', map '?', @data;
    $insert = $dbhandle->prepare($insert);
    $insert->execute(@data) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

but note that you will have to call `prepare` every time the parameter counts changes.

Note also that your identifier `addData` should ideally be `add_data`, as upper case letters are generally reserved for global identifiers.

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot actually. My @data array is always the same size. You're way even looks much cleaner.Thank you!